# Images are not displaying in my view

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter

This is my view file:-

```
<h1>Welcome <?php echo "$username " ?> </h1>
<h3>
<?php echo "your User Id is: $id "?></br>
<?php echo "your User name is: $username "?></br>
<?php echo "your Password is: $password"?></br>
<?php echo "your Profile picture is: $image"?></br>
</h3>
<img src="../files/<?php echo $image ?>" alt="Profile picture" width="100" height="130">
```

and my files folder is outside of the application folder.

Comment: are you getting value for `$image`?

Comment: look at your browser console if image is not missing or mistyped (error 404)

Comment: yes i am getting the value of $image...........

Comment: please elaborate your file structure.. you may not getting the image path.

Comment: What is the value of `$image`, and where is that image placed on the server ( wich folder structure)?

Comment: check your console by pressing F12. There might be any error..

Comment: If the image is outside the webserver you cannot access it ... apache only provides access to your htdocs put the files in the htdocs

Comment: have you set base_url in your project? If so try with `<img src="<?php echo $base_url();?>/files/<?php echo $image ?>" alt="Profile picture" width="100" height="130">`

Comment: this image is placed in the files folder, and files folder is place out side the application folder, and i am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: thats ok, are you getting any error,in console.Thats my question

Comment: yes i get an error in console and error is:
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.2.0/index.php/files/american_express.png"

Comment: you didn't setup your base_url and htaccess yet. Am I right?

Comment: yes dude Vaisakh Pc, and now please tell me how can i set base url

Comment: set in config.php

$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: and in htaccess file
write
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /directory_name/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory_name/index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change**

```
<img src="../files/<?php echo $image ?>" alt="Profile picture" width="100" height="130">
```

**to**

```
<img src="http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.2.0/files/<?php echo $image ?>" alt="Profile picture" width="100" height="130">
```

Answer (score 0):

before view images upload them using `$this->upload->data() helper   and  [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get your folder structure, considering my mistake when i started, use base_url();

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/path/to/image/from_web_app_root">
```

make sure you load it before you use it.

Here is the link: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

if URL Helper is not loaded in your /application/config/autoload.php file , load the URL helper in your controller by $this->load->helper('url');
then write the code as bellow:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>files/<?php echo $image ?>" alt="Profile picture" width="100" height="130">
```